# How to specify file path Dynamically in logback.xml

Tags: logback

I am new to Logback, I am trying to add file path dynamically, with a property file, for both windows and Linux.

Here is the code sinppet I have, how can I get the value to ${MY_HOME}

```
<appender name="SERVER_FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
    <file>${MY_HOME}/server.log</file>
    <append>true</append>
    <encoder>
      <pattern>%d [%thread] %-5level %logger{35} - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>
```

Answer (score 10):

Typically this is a system property, there are some answers that touch on this but only provide one part of the answer.  These are:

- [Logback.xml configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18204990/logback-xml-configuration/19290534#19290534)
- [logback how to set destination folder for log files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27764071/logback-how-to-set-destination-folder-for-log-files/27768207#27768207)

But the manual on [configuration](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html) shows that the mechanism is quite flexible

> As in many scripting languages, logback configuration files support definition and substitution of variables. Variables can be defined within the configuration file itself, in an external file, in an external resource or even computed and defined on the fly.

In summary you have a number of options for defining the value of MY_HOME:

**In the file**

You are able to define the value in the file itself with:

```
<property name="MY_HOME" value="/home/myhome"/>
```

**In the system properties**

You can arrange for it to be set as a system property, most likely when you start the JVM.

```
java -DMY_HOME="/home/myhome" ...
```

**From a property file on your system**

You can arrange for logback to read a property file:

```
<property file="/opt/example/instance_1/properties/system.properties" />
```

**From the classpath**

You can write a properties file into a resources directory or into a jar and read it out as a resource, using the classpath.

```
<property resource="prod.properties" />
```

**Using the property definer**

You can arrange to call into your code, by using a property definer. For example:

```
<define name="MY_HOME" class="biz.nowhere.HomePropertyDefiner">
   <application>app</application>
</define>
```

Where that class is something like (as an example):

```
public class HomePropertyDefiner extends PropertyDefinerBase {

  private String application;

  @Override
  public String getPropertyValue() {
    return String.format("/opt/%s/%s", application, MyInstanceManager.instancePath());
  }

  public void setApplication(String application) {
      this.application = application;
  }

}
```

Comment: I had some inconsistent `ch.qos.logback.core.util.IncompatibleClassException` issue with `ch.qos.logback.core.PropertyDefinerBase` had to replace `extends PropertyDefinerBase` with `extends ch.qos.logback.core.spi.ContextAwareBase implements ch.qos.logback.core.spi.PropertyDefiner`